# @keyframes animation between three DIV's show its content at start

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an animation that kind works. I just want to fix the problem that all the content of the 3 div's that are suppose to alternate, shows up on top of others on the beginning. After 9 seconds it works like it should.

I have tried many solutions and properties on similar questions here, to no avail.

Here is the code:

```css
.maintext div {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}

.maintext h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    text-align: center;
}

.maintext h3 {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 35px;
}

@keyframes txt3FadeInOut {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    17% { opacity: 1; }
    33% { opacity: 0; }
    82% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.maintext div:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation: txt3FadeInOut 9s ease-in-out 6s infinite;
}

.maintext div:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation: txt3FadeInOut 9s ease-in-out 3s infinite;
}

.maintext div:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation: txt3FadeInOut 9s ease-in-out 0s infinite;
}
```

```html
<div class="maintext" >
    <div id="txt3" class="containertxt self-clear">
        <h1>
            First text
        </h1>
        <br>
        <h3>
            first text
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="txt3" class="containertxt self-clear">
            <h1>
                Second text
            </h1>
            <br>
            <h3>
                second text
            </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="txt3" class="containertxt self-clear">
            <h1>
                Third text
            </h1>
            <br>
            <h3>
                Third text
            </h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u3x57wnL/23/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to build three different animations such as:

```
@keyframes txt1FadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 1; }
  16% { opacity: 1; }
  32% { opacity: 0; }
  48% { opacity: 0; }
  64% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes txt2FadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  16% { opacity: 0; }
  32% { opacity: 1; }
  48% { opacity: 1; }
  64% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes txt3FadeInOut {
  0% { opacity: 0; }
  16% { opacity: 0; }
  32% { opacity: 0; }
  48% { opacity: 0; }
  64% { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

And then run them for the same amount of time

Comment: I tried your solution and it make it better for sure. But the loop transition, from 3 to 1 it is not smooth. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You could rinse and repeat the same logic so add one more step to the succession of steps. But the other answer is better imo

Answer (score 0):

Since your animation lasts 9 seconds, you can subtract 9 seconds from the delays and keep those being the same - but to start the animation with the animation already running.

So, a delay of 6s becomes one of 6 - 9 = -3s.

Also, you can share the common properties to make your code more DRY

```css
.maintext div {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.maintext h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.maintext h3 {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  line-height: 35px;
}

@keyframes txt3FadeInOut {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  82% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.maintext div {
  animation: txt3FadeInOut 9s ease-in-out infinite;
  }

.maintext div:nth-of-type(1) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

.maintext div:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: -6s;
}
```

```html
<div class="maintext">
  <div id="txt3" class="containertxt self-clear">
    <h1>
      First text
    </h1>
    <br>
    <h3>
      first text
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="txt3" class="containertxt self-clear">
    <h1>
      Second text
    </h1>
    <br>
    <h3>
      second text
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="txt3" class="containertxt self-clear">
    <h1>
      Third text
    </h1>
    <br>
    <h3>
      Third text
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, for the solution and advice! I have been two days working around this issue!

Comment: Happy that it helped